gitlab-ce 16 not running after updating
Due to the necessity of update all my Ubuntu environment to go on a latest version (22.04). I took this opportunity to update also my gitlab-ce. However, after uninstalling an old version (13.12.8) to go on version 16.11.2, my attempt create me some error with PostgreSQL and Grafana which now doesn't start.
Result from gitlab-ctl status after first start:
run: alertmanager: (pid 105767) 1024s; run: log: (pid 105758) 1024s
run: gitaly: (pid 105761) 1024s; run: log: (pid 105757) 1024s
run: gitlab-exporter: (pid 105783) 1024s; run: log: (pid 105772) 1024s
run: gitlab-kas: (pid 105777) 1024s; run: log: (pid 105763) 1024s
run: gitlab-workhorse: (pid 105780) 1024s; run: log: (pid 105770) 1024s
down: grafana: 1s, normally up, want up; run: log: (pid 105774) 1024s
run: logrotate: (pid 105785) 1024s; run: log: (pid 105779) 1024s
run: nginx: (pid 105775) 1024s; run: log: (pid 105764) 1024s
run: node-exporter: (pid 105776) 1024s; run: log: (pid 105771) 1024s
run: postgres-exporter: (pid 105773) 1024s; run: log: (pid 105759) 1024s
down: postgresql: 1s, normally up, want up; run: log: (pid 105766) 1024s
run: prometheus: (pid 105778) 1024s; run: log: (pid 105762) 1024s
run: puma: (pid 110565) 1s; run: log: (pid 105754) 1024s
run: redis: (pid 105765) 1024s; run: log: (pid 105755) 1024s
run: redis-exporter: (pid 105768) 1024s; run: log: (pid 105756) 1024s
run: sidekiq: (pid 110550) 4s; run: log: (pid 105769) 1024s

First of all I had only PostgreSQL doesn't starting.
I try to check logs and see this error after the command line gitlab-rake db:migrate:status:
rake aborted!                           
ActiveRecord::DatabaseConnectionError: There is an issue connecting to your database with your username/password, username: gitlab.

Please check your database configuration to ensure the username/password are valid.
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:124:in `read_write'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:126:in `write_using_load_balancer'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:96:in `method_missing'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'

Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: connection to server on socket "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:124:in `read_write'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:126:in `write_using_load_balancer'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:96:in `method_missing'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate:status
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

I also try to check more information about this issue with this command gitlab-ctl tail postgresql:
2024-05-15_08:40:29.65182 2024-05-15 08:40:29.651 GMT [112456] FATAL:  configuration file "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data/runtime.conf" contains errors
2024-05-15_08:40:30.67456 2024-05-15 08:40:30.674 GMT [112460] LOG:  unrecognized configuration parameter "wal_keep_segments" in file "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data/runtime.conf" line 30

After checking other forum link to this subject I didn't found anything working.
gitlab-ctl reconfigure stop on database migration, and I'm scared that I lost some content of the database by a miss updating.
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

rails_migration[gitlab-rails] (gitlab::database_migrations line 51) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: bash_hide_env[migrate gitlab-rails database] (gitlab::database_migrations line 20) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'

Adding to this when I restart gitlab-ctl restart everything run.
ok: run: alertmanager: (pid 117384) 0s
ok: run: gitaly: (pid 117394) 0s
ok: run: gitlab-exporter: (pid 117408) 0s
ok: run: gitlab-kas: (pid 117455) 0s
ok: run: gitlab-workhorse: (pid 117464) 0s
ok: run: grafana: (pid 117536) 0s
ok: run: logrotate: (pid 117540) 0s
ok: run: nginx: (pid 117547) 1s
ok: run: node-exporter: (pid 117552) 0s
ok: run: postgres-exporter: (pid 117559) 1s
ok: run: postgresql: (pid 117576) 0s
ok: run: prometheus: (pid 117582) 0s
ok: run: puma: (pid 117591) 0s
ok: run: redis: (pid 117596) 0s
ok: run: redis-exporter: (pid 117605) 1s
ok: run: sidekiq: (pid 117615) 0s

But when I look the status gitlab-ctl status grafana and PostgreSQL turn down.
run: alertmanager: (pid 117384) 54s; run: log: (pid 105758) 2796s
run: gitaly: (pid 117394) 53s; run: log: (pid 105757) 2796s
run: gitlab-exporter: (pid 117408) 52s; run: log: (pid 105772) 2796s
run: gitlab-kas: (pid 117455) 41s; run: log: (pid 105763) 2796s
run: gitlab-workhorse: (pid 117464) 40s; run: log: (pid 105770) 2796s
down: grafana: 0s, normally up, want up; run: log: (pid 105774) 2796s
run: logrotate: (pid 117540) 22s; run: log: (pid 105779) 2796s
run: nginx: (pid 117547) 22s; run: log: (pid 105764) 2796s
run: node-exporter: (pid 117552) 21s; run: log: (pid 105771) 2796s
run: postgres-exporter: (pid 117559) 21s; run: log: (pid 105759) 2796s
down: postgresql: 0s, normally up, want up; run: log: (pid 105766) 2796s
run: prometheus: (pid 117582) 17s; run: log: (pid 105762) 2796s
run: puma: (pid 117648) 6s; run: log: (pid 105754) 2796s
run: redis: (pid 117596) 16s; run: log: (pid 105755) 2796s
run: redis-exporter: (pid 117605) 16s; run: log: (pid 105756) 2796s
run: sidekiq: (pid 117615) 13s; run: log: (pid 105769) 2796s

I have seen this question but neither answer solved my issue.
If any more information is needed, feel free to comment.

you can't upgrade from 13.12.8 to directly 16.11.2.
You can use this tool from gitlab to know which steps you need to do.
https://gitlab-com.gitlab.io/support/toolbox/upgrade-path/?current=13.12.15&edition=ce
You need to upgrade multiple times to avoid issues.
14.0.12 => 14.3.6 => 14.9.5 => 14.10.5 => 15.0.5 => 15.4.6 => 15.11.13 => 16.3.7 => 16.7.7 => 16.11.3 => 17.0.1
apt-get install gitlab-ce=14.0.12-ce.0

Your error on PostgreSQL is probably because you did upgrade it to v13 or higher which renames wal_keep_segments.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/release-13.html

Rename configuration parameter wal_keep_segments to wal_keep_size
(Fujii Masao)
This determines how much WAL to retain for standby servers. It is
specified in megabytes, rather than number of files as with the old
parameter. If you previously used wal_keep_segments, the following
formula will give you an approximately equivalent setting:
wal_keep_size = wal_keep_segments * wal_segment_size (typically 16MB)

